# can the findmax function of Julia be modified so it doesnt take the NaN values?

Tags: python, julia

Since i have NaN in my df (they cant be replaced for any other value), the findmax() function returns NaN as the largest values found, which is not useful at all...
I've been reading several blogs and posts and found nothing.
To be more specific, is there anyway that i can make this function like python's np.nanmax()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler solution (and faster, too, it seems) than going through `skipmissing` is:

```
foo(itr) = maximum(x for x in itr if !isnan(x))
```

Comment: Right - this is a better solution. I initially considered it, but it does not work with `findmax`, but `skipmissing` does not work with it either.

Answer (score 3):

`findmax` is not the same as `np.nanmax`. I assume you want the functionality of `np.nanmax`, then do:

```
julia> your_vector = [1.0, NaN, 3.0, NaN, 2.0]
5-element Vector{Float64}:
   1.0
 NaN
   3.0
 NaN
   2.0

julia> maximum(skipmissing(isnan(x) ? missing : x for x in your_vector))
3.0

julia> your_vector = [NaN, NaN]
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 NaN
 NaN

julia> maximum(skipmissing(isnan(x) ? missing : x for x in your_vector))
ERROR: ArgumentError: reducing over an empty collection is not allowed
```

The trick is to replace `NaN` with `missing` (but without materializing the result to save memory) and then skip `missing`. Note that I have proposed a solution that errors when only `NaN` are present. In Python you would get a warning then, but in Julia we usually avoid printing warnings as they can be very easily lost unnoticed and instead require and explicit handling or error situation.

Now you might ask why there is no simple solution for `NaN`, but there is a solution for `missing` (as with `missing` you would just write `maximum(skipmissing(your_vector))`)? The answer is that `NaN` values are not typically encountered in Julia codes (unless indeed you have some computation that produces `NaN`) while in Python `NaN` is often used as a value that signals that we have a missing value in data (which is common).

Comment: What @DNF proposed is better.